# Can not install MySQL driver from DataGrip

Tags: mysql, driver, datagrip

For some reason I can not install MySQL driver from DataGrip. When trying to download missing driver files I get

> Failed to download 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar':
> Connection reset

I tried to disable my Firewall and I can ping `repo1.maven.org` but driver still can not be downloaded.

- Windows 10 Pro
- DataGrip 2020.1

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please check if the link from the error message is accessible via the browser? 
Also, please, add the following lines to `Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings`:

`com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests`,
`#com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests`,
`com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy`,
`#com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy`.

After that, restart IDE, reproduce the problem once again, collect logs (`Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data`) and share using the [JetBrains Uploads](https://uploads.jetbrains.com/) service. Don't forget to post the ID you receive here.

Comment: Have you tried to download driver directly from maven via link https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run DataGrip as Administrator.

Then try to download the missing driver files. When completed, close DataGrip and open it again (this time not as administrator). Now you should be able to connect to your desired database.

Hope it helps.